# How to find the type of content inside req.body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, httpresponse

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request the type of body can be of either type:

1. ArrayBuffer
2. Blob
3. formData
4. JSON
5. text

Is there a way for the receiving side to know what type it is? The reason I ask is since I am getting a POST message from a 3rd party where the req.body is empty.

```
// my code
console.info("Headers: ", req.headers); // shows headers
console.log("Data: ", req.body); // shows nothing
```

However, after further inspection, it seems that I need to process the data as follows (since its using ReadableStream):

```
   // code from a 3rd party library
   req.on('data', function (chunk) {
       data += chunk;
   });

   req.on('end', function () {
       var messageData = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log("Data: ", messageData); //shows data
    }
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't appear to be related to the fetch API (which is the documentation you linked to).

Comment: Use `res.headers['content-type]'` to investigate the body content type.

Comment: @Quentin - I am exploring it, as and as I am experimenting.

Comment: @alexmac - thats a good point; I was expecting req.body to spit something out, but after reading the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser , things are making more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do it yourself but most people use [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and the [Body Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) library to avoid having loads of boilerplate code to do the parsing for them.

Comment: I will eventually use a library like express or body. I was confused about req.body not printing anything, but after reading the link you attached for Body Parser I am getting a better understanding. Thanks!